# Is SyncLock reetrant?

Tags: .net, vb.net, multithreading, synclock

I have the following code in a class that manages refreshing some object automatically that also allows you to manually refresh. I want to make it thread-safe.

```
Public Function ForceRefresh() As Foo
  DoRefresh()
  ResetTimer()
  Return Me.CurrentFoo
End Function

Private Sub DoRefresh()
  Me._currentFoo = Me._retriever.GetTheFoo()
End Sub
```

I'm tempted to `Synclock` both of these methods:

- `ForceRefresh`: So we don't get multiple consumer threads trying to force a refresh and reset the timer at the same time
- `DoRefresh`: So we don't try to `GetTheFoo()` if we're already in the middle of trying to retrieve one. I'm using `System.Threading.Timer` which might call back on any of the `ThreadPool` threads, so simply using a flag might not be appropriate (but maybe is still necessary?)

... like this:

```
Private _syncRoot As New Object

Public Function ForceRefresh() As Foo
  Synclock _syncRoot
    'Snip ...
  End Synclock
End Function

Private Sub DoRefresh()
  Synclock _syncRoot
    'Snip ...
  End Synclock
End Sub
```

But then I end up trying to `Synclock` on `_syncRoot` twice when calling `ForceRefresh`... now if `Synclock` is reentrant then nesting these won't be an issue. The [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3a86s51t%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) documentation page seems to imply that this is the case, but doesn't say it explicitly.

Note: I'm gonna give this a try myself, but I didn't see anything about this on StackOverflow and thought it was an useful question to have answered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The SyncLock statement uses Monitor.Enter() under the hood.  The MSDN library says:

> It is legal for the same thread to invoke Enter more than once without it blocking

Which means it is re-entrant.  Easy to check btw.

Comment: You beat me too it over lunch ;) Thanks!